# Is it possible to change a line of code of a cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a line of code in a cocoapod that I would like to change (at least for a test). Changing the code by itself is possible, but how do I get it to recompile, so that I have a new 'libPods-xyz.a' file whith the modiifed version?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just seems to work as expected: change the code, recompile, done. For some reason it didn't work yesterday, thats why I asked.